# Call to default values (MySQL) in a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For the sake of an experiment, we're working with the following procedure (same DB, multiple tables):

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.insertTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hash_id int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _charge varchar(45), _plea bit(2), _sentence varchar(45), _dob int, _state_id int, _state_id_status bit(1))

begin

START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO MYDB.person (`first_name`, `last_name`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_first_name, _last_name, _hash_id);

  INSERT INTO MYDB.id_crimes (`id`, `id_status`, `criminal_status`, `charge`, `plea`, `sentence`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_id_status, _id, _criminal_status, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO MYDB.dob_state (`state_ID`, `stateID_status`, `dob`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_dob, _state_id, _state_id_status, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO MYDB.timestamps (`create_time`, `update_time`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_create_time, _update_time, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  COMMIT;

end//

delimiter ;
```

We're running into difficulties when trying to call the procedure, however. The `DEFAULT` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` values are throwing errors (call seen below). Any help would be appreciated!

```
call mysql.insertTables (`Debbie`, `Hopkins`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  DEFAULT, 1, 123456789, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 12211985, 12345678, 1)
```

P.S. The `hashID` value is stored only as a foreign key in every table except person, so I'm not sure we need to insert it (as `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) in every table. The first issue mentioned is the biggest concern, though. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `DEFAULT` is context sensitive within an `INSERT` statement only (some systems may support it as well within `UPDATE`). You can't use `DEFAULT` within the context of calling a stored procedure. Also, MySQL does not yet support default values for stored procedure parameters either.

An alternative can be:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.insertTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hash_id int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _charge varchar(45), _plea bit(2), _sentence varchar(45), _dob int, _state_id int, _state_id_status bit(1))

begin

START TRANSACTION;

  # use the default value if the parameter is zero or null
  IF _hash_id = 0 OR _hash_id IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO MYDB.person (`first_name`, `last_name`)
      VALUES (_first_name, _last_name);
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO MYDB.person (`first_name`, `last_name`, `hashID`)
      VALUES (_first_name, _last_name, _hash_id);
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO MYDB.id_crimes (`id`, `id_status`, `criminal_status`, `charge`, `plea`, `sentence`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_id_status, _id, _criminal_status, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO MYDB.dob_state (`state_ID`, `stateID_status`, `dob`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_dob, _state_id, _state_id_status, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  IF _update_time IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO MYDB.timestamps (`create_time`, `hashID`)
      VALUES (_create_time, LAST_INSERT_ID());
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO MYDB.timestamps (`create_time`, `update_time`, `hashID`)
      VALUES (_create_time, _update_time, LAST_INSERT_ID());
  END IF;

  COMMIT;

end//

delimiter ;

call mysql.insertTables (`Debbie`, `Hopkins`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       NULL, # passing NULL here will cause the function to insert the default value
       0, # passing 0 value for _hash_id will insert the table's default value
       1, 123456789, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 12211985, 12345678, 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work - at least not for me using MariaDB v10.1.6 - if I call a stored procedure with fewer than the defined number of parameters, I get an error that I haven't passed the required number of parameters, and the stored procedure is NOT run. Is this something specific to the version I am running? Or is there some other directive I am missing in my code / environment / conf file that would allow me to call SP's with fewer than the number of parameters defined, so I can make use of the "IF ParamName IS NULL THEN ParamName = 'DefaultValue' END IF; " example? I HAVE searched for this - b

Comment: @DavidBlum you have to include all stored procedure arguments in MariaDB, even though MariaDB & MySQL do not seem to default values for arguments, or even overloading as yet. There are, however, ways to simulate overloading (and thus missing arguments) via a careful combination of stored procedures and session variables, eg http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/06/16/overloading-procedures/

Answer (score 4):

The point of "default" values is that they are the **default values**.  You Don't need to list them in the insert query at all.  They'll be inserted automatically.

To pass `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a parameter, you probably need to use the equivalent pseudo-function, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`... which is the same as `NOW()`

Stop and consider `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  The default value here is only `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` -- `ON UPDATE ...` is a completely unrelated directive, so here again, you need to just pass `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` if you want to pass these into procedures... though that us unnecessary if you modify the inside queries not to specify the columns you are free to exclude, because they have default values.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make these changes:

```
call mysql.insertTables (`Debbie`, `Hopkins`,
    NULL, NULL, NULL,   -- Changed
    1, 123456789, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 12211985, 12345678, 1)
```

`NULL` tells the `INSERT` to invoke the `DEFAULTs`.